# Problems with longitude and latitude in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

In Tableau, I have a problem with the longitude and latitude of this dataset https://data.lacity.org/Public-Safety/Crime-Data-from-2020-to-Present/2nrs-mtv8 <- From LAPD in the US.

On the map, it does not show any points. Anyone who may know why this problem occurs?

Hope you can help me out!

Best Regards!

Update: This is how my "map" looks when i plot it in :)
[MAP_Whichisnotamap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y454.png)

Answer (score 2):

I can get the Map with all locations (except a few null ones)

You can review my work here and reach out to me for more details.
[LAPD Crime Tableau Dashboard](https://public.tableau.com/views/LAPD_Incidents/LAPD-CrimeDataAnalysis?:language=en-US&:display_count=n&:origin=viz_share_link)
[image]

Comment: This looks amazing! 

Did you put the area name as a particular geocode (I think I have tried all) or did you have to change some other settings or values?
Thanks! :)

Comment: i simply dragged it into the color section, no change of settings as such.hope this solves the case, for more details you can connect me here : https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/debayan.kar/vizzes

Comment: Hi again, I tried to copy what you have done and develop my own but it does not give me the same result as you have reached. It gives me only the grid with the lat and lon points and names of areas. I will try to add a picture of the result.

I have connected/followed but did not find any direct messaging option :)

Comment: @FrederikN.Pedersen Please mark the answer as solved, as this issue is closed per our discussion